# prime numbers not displaying correct answers

Tags: java, for-loop, boolean

my code works for only a few numbers, but it fails altogether on most numbers and I can't figure out why. It's meant to return the number and then true if its prime, or false if its not prime.

```
int first = 6; 
int second = 7;
boolean primeFirst = false;
boolean primeSecond = false;


//first prime checker
for (int x = 2; x< (Math.sqrt(first)); x++)
{
  primeFirst = true; //prime
  if (first% x == 0)
  {
    primeFirst = false; //not prime
  }             
}

//second prime checker
for (int x = 2; x< (Math.sqrt(second)); x++)
{
  primeSecond = true; 
  if (second % x == 0)
  {
    primeSecond = false;                  
  }            
}

System.out.println(first + " is " + primeFirst);
System.out.println(second + " is " + primeSecond);
```

Comment: If `x` is always less than the square root of your number in question (as you have written), what result will you get for the number 4?

Comment: Please provide an example of where it fails.

Comment: @c-otto it fails for 21, and 22, but works for 23 and 24

Comment: @khelwood for 4, I get false (not prime)

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you are setting `primeFirst` to true in every iteration of your loop. You should set it only *before* the loop, so it won't be reset back to true after you have already found a factor. Same for `primeSecond`. That's why 21 comes out as prime.

Secondly, you are not checking every possible factor, because your loop condition is `x< (Math.sqrt(first))`. That means the loop will stop before testing the square root itelf, which is why 9 comes out as prime.

Here is a possible fixed version:

```
boolean primeFirst = true;
double sqrtFirst = Math.sqrt(first);
for (int x = 2; x <= sqrtFirst; ++x) {
    if (first%x==0) {
        primeFirst = false;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: 4 comes out as false (not prime)

Comment: @miataaaaaa Oh yes. It would because of `primeFirst` only being set to true inside the loop. OK then, 9 rather than 4.

Answer (score 2):

I think, this works(https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-determine-a-prime-number-in-java/):

```
boolean isPrime(int n) {
    for(int i = 2; i <= Math.sqrt(n); i++) {
        if(n%i==0)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

I've tried it out with a few different numbers and everything worked correctly!

Comment: the last possible divisor for n is not n but sqrt(n)

Comment: But I think, that causes the problem. When I tried it with `Math.sqrt(first)`, it didn't work with for example 4.

Comment: Oh now I see the mistake in my code! I should use `<=`, but not `<`. Thanks! I've edited the answer!

Answer (score 2):

If you see properly, value of `primeFirst` & `primeSecond` are dependent only on the last iterations of the loop. This might work for prime numbers but will certainly fail for many non-prime numbers. 
Another problem with your code is that `x<(Math.sqrt(second))`. It should be `x<=(Math.sqrt(second))`.

I would suggest you to not use this logic instead, use [Wilson's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson%27s_theorem).
It says if for a number `p`, `(p-1)!+1` is divisible by `p` then the number is prime.

```
static int factorial(int n){
    if(n==0)
        return 1;
    else return n*factorial(n-1);
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    int p = 6; //any number you want to test

    if((factorial(p-1)+1)%p==0)
        System.out.println(p+" is a prime number");
    else System.out.println(p+" is not a prime number");
}
```

Comment: This only works for sufficiently small numbers up to 31. For 32, your factorial returns -2147483648, from 34 on they are all 0.

Answer (score 1):

you have using it in a wrong way, you must add `=` in the `for` loop condition.

also I think there is no need for `Math.sqrt(first)`, and for all these booleans.

see this simple code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = 2; i <= 100; i++) {
        System.out.println(i + " is " + isPrime(i));
    }
}

public static boolean isPrime(int num) {
    for (int i = 2; i < num; i++) {
        if (num % i == 0)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: That is, what I wrote one minute ago!

Comment: Ok! Maybe! But I think you need `Math.sqrt`. It's not nesessary, but the last possible divisor isn't i, but sqrt(i). Than the computer doesn't have to work so hard ;-) so in the for-loop, the second parameter should be `i <= Math.sqrt(num)`. I did that wrong too!

Comment: I know, but it is not a big deal to loop over numbers for today computers expect he want it for a limited resources machine.

Comment: You're right... But for example you wouldn't multiply two Integers, if it isn't nesessary and you never need the result. Also, if it wouldn't make a big different to the machine. So I've just edited my answer, and I think, you should do that too.

Answer (score -1):

Using the '**Math.sqrt(checknum)**' method for prime number checking, hepls reduce loop time by iterating only up to the square root for the number being checked. this is becuase factors of a number come in pairs, one smaller than the square root and one larger.
By checking up to the square root, you cover all possible factors efficiently, optimizing the process.

```
    int Checknum=6;
    boolean primefirst=true;
    for(int i=2;i<=(Math.sqrt(Checknum));i++)
    {
        if(Checknum%i==0)
        {
            primefirst=false;
        }
        
    }
    String output=primefirst==true? "this is prime Number":"this is Not prime Number";
    
    System.out.println(Checknum+" "+output);
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  As it is, it's hard to see how this differs from the code in the question.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including what you changed and any assumptions you've made.